# Number of solutions by generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

**Q4 Find the number of ordered triples $(x, y, z)$ of nonnegative integers satisfying the
conditions:

(i) x ≤ y ≤ z;

(ii) x + y + z ≤ 100.
(RMO 2003 INDIA)**

My approach to the problem is through generating function.

Let y = x + a
and z = y + b

Hence 3x + 2a + b + c = 100

Hence number of solution is

*[x^100] in*  *{ (1-x^3)(1-x^2)(1-x)^2 }^-1*

I am not able to find it

Comment: C is just a dummy variable .

Comment: We need to transform the inequality to an equation

Comment: The problem is how to find the coefficient of x^100 in that expansion

Comment: I see what you are doing with $c$... Ok, I will rethink this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Wolframalpha, I get 30,787:

[Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B1%2F((1-x)%5E2(1-x%5E2)(1-x%5E3)),%7Bx,0,100%7D%5D)

I used the SeriesCoefficient function in Wolframalpha.

Comment: Your answer is correct . But is there any method to calculate it manually?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "calculate it manually"? You can try partial fraction decomposition, but that would be messy.